# How do I move a single item to the right in a flexbox container?

Tags: html, css, jsx

I'm trying to move the "14" that you see in the picture below all the way to the right of the black bordered container it's in and currently it's inside a flexbox container called `card-footer`:

[image]

How can I do this? Here is my CSS code:

```
.card-footer {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    padding-top: 0;
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.num-icon {
    justify-content: end;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Here is my HTML (JSX - react project) code:

```
<div className="card-footer">
    <button className="btn">Details</button>
    {project.assignment_type === 'Mini Case Studies' &&
        <>
            <a href={project.sharepoint_link} without="true" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
                <button className="btn btn-outline">Download</button>
            </a>
            <a href={PDF} without="true" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
                <button className="btn">Preview</button>
            </a>
        </>
    }
    {project.assignment_type !== 'Mini Case Studies' &&
        <button className="btn btn-outline" onClick={function(e){ navigator.clipboard.writeText(project.goal); alert('Text copied to clipboard!') }}
            >
            Copy to Clipboard
        </button>
    }
    // THIS IS WHAT I'M TRYING TO MOVE TO THE RIGHT
    <div className="num-icon">
        14
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just set `margin-left: auto`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `margin-left:auto`

```
.num-icon {
    margin-left:auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<div className="card-footer">
    <div className="btn-container"> //Add these 2 items in a div and keep the element that are trying to move separate
    <button className="btn">Details</button>
    {project.assignment_type === 'Mini Case Studies' &&
        <>
            <a href={project.sharepoint_link} without="true" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
                <button className="btn btn-outline">Download</button>
            </a>
            <a href={PDF} without="true" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
                <button className="btn">Preview</button>
            </a>
        </>
    }
    {project.assignment_type !== 'Mini Case Studies' &&
        <button className="btn btn-outline" onClick={function(e){ navigator.clipboard.writeText(project.goal); alert('Text copied to clipboard!') }}
            >
            Copy to Clipboard
        </button>
    }
    </div>
    // THIS IS WHAT I'M TRYING TO MOVE TO THE RIGHT
    <div className="num-icon">
        14
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.card-footer {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    padding-top: 0;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between; //This will keep both elements at opposite ends of the container
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.num-icon {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}
```